# AWS get all objects inside of folder in S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to get all the URLs of objects stored in a folder. I will only have one level of folders so I am not concerned with nested folders. I have read the PHP client API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html) for S3 but can't seem to find a way to accomplish this.

I found this code from StackOverflow to get the size of contents:

```
List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
long totalSize  = 0;
int  totalItems = 0;
for (Bucket bucket : buckets)
{
    ObjectListing objects = s3.listObjects(bucket.getName());
    do {
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            totalSize += objectSummary.getSize();
            totalItems++;
        }
        objects = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
    } while (objects.isTruncated());
    System.out.println("You have " + buckets.size() + " Amazon S3 bucket(s), " +
                    "containing " + totalItems + " objects with a total size of " + totalSize + " bytes.");
}
```

Which is close to something I want, except I do not want all the items in a bucket, I want all the items in a certain bucket's folder. My second question is how much would I need to spend to accomplish this as there doesn't seem to be an get/put commands being used so I am not sure how much Amazon charges to for this operation?

Answer (score 1):

[`ListObjects` takes a `prefix` argument](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects). That prefix is the "directory" inside a bucket.

Comment: So what is the financial cost of this operation? As well, is this algorithm efficient? Say I have 10000000 objects, since S3 is flat does it search for all objects?

Comment: It's almost free (in terms of cost); 1/2 cent per 10k requests. It's generally advisable to not do this operation as a standard part of your code- there are typically much better way to structure things so this isn't something you need to do often.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What would be the better practice then?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. If you post your use case as a new question, link it here. You can use SNS/SQS and possibly Lambda.